# Is there any meaning to political criticism by people who are not in the government?

Tags: political-philosophy, politics, critical-thinking, philosophy-of-political-science

There are all sorts of people who criticize the government for various good or bad decisions.

It could be meaningful if they have studied it to great depth and give constructive criticism, but, that's not always the case.

Is there any meaning to political criticism, or any political debate by people outside government.

Also, is it a valid argument to say that people should join the government and make the change instead of criticism?

Comment: In a democratic state each citizen is supposed to have equal say in public matters, therefore every one has an opinion and many will have an opinion opposed to that of the people in power, the expression of which will constitute a criticism. So there can be no democracy without criticism of the government by people outside of it. Also, not everyone can be in the government, so not everybody can join. What is more, joining requires winning in some kind of selection process like elections. I am quite glad people with views radicaly different than mine can't just join the government on a whim.

Comment: @armand Like any other field, people who aren't involved will never fully understand how it works, they will criticize from their own perspective. So, unconstructive criticism is pretty meaningless. Unless you provide a solution, and prove that it's feasible enough and is only not implemented because of incompetence of government, any other criticism that points out obvious things, and most political debates sound pretty meaningless.

Comment: Why would being outside of government prevent studying it to great depth? Or prevent criticism from being constructive? And why wouldn't government benefit from both inside and outside perspective, like everything else? Besides, if enough people, with or without deep knowledge, are unconstructively unhappy with how the government is run it gets reformed or overthrown, so it is meaningful enough to be consequential. Providing "solutions" and "proving" something in politics are nice but academic dreams, life is too messy for it most of the time, and  the gut can detect what theory can not.

Comment: @abhishekchaudhary: I totally agree that uninformed criticism is terrible. That's why education is crucial in democratic political systems. Although, as Conifold suggests, people don't need to be part of a government to be informed on a given subject (and alas, we have enough examples of people who are elected officials but don't seem to be educated about anything...), and uninformed people are entitled to voicing their discontentment. If you really think any form of criticism is pointless, I suggest you move to North Korea, where you are guaranteed to not loose any time in political debate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Governments generally don't innovate, because those who have succeeded in the old system generally have a bias to prevent change. This is a major reason why philosophy of politics exists, to get to grips from first principles with how politics can be better.

Social contract theories became more convincing for modern people, than divine right of kings. The backstop against tyranny in that framing is not just a right, but a duty to revolt. In practice, the realistic threat of revolt, has generally proved better than actual revolt which has many unwanted consequences, and which is unlikely to make change in stable ways. But threat of unrest has been crucial to most positive political and social change.

Debate shouldn't be about who is qualified. Only people who won't commit to good conduct and mutual respect and the value of debate, should be excluded. Then, best practice can sorted out through pursuasion in such debates.

Representative rather than direct democracy has proven itself better historically, underlined by things like Brexit, and Switzerland's recent ban on face coverings during a respiratory pandemic out of fear of Islamic culture.  But when concerns are persistently not listened to, for instance allowing bad behaviour by big businesses who pay off representatives, destabilising forces build up like conspiracy theories. So a balance is needed.

We should be trying to accrue tactics and mechanisms that improve outcomes politucally. Habeus corpus, universal sufferage, division of powers, rights to protest, must be taught understood and valued, such that people can defend them in debates, and if necessary in the streets. Sortition in the form of citizen assemblies, could be a way of dealing with the ignorance you speak about, like that drove the Brexit vote; while managing tensions from a political class with different concerns to the wider population.

Comment: Would be perfect if not for your unnecessary plug in of your personal opinion about brexit.

Comment: @armand: Brexit cannot achieve the objectives that motivated voters that backed it, in fact it will specifically harm regions that voted for it like Wales and Cornwall. Like Trump's record in government, it is objectively indefensible by anyone interested in evidence https://www.opendemocracy.net/en/opendemocracyuk/why-brexit-its-english-stupid/

Comment: Dunno. In my own experience, the more people are informed about how the EU works and its track record of achievements, the more they tend to want out. Those who want to stay usually haven't given much thought to the subject, they just repeat what they heard. Totally agree about Trump but why bring him up out of the blue? Maybe some Pavlovian conditioning here...

Comment: @armand: We'll be bound by the rules of our largest trading partner, but no longer able to influence. If that sounds good to you, the indictment isn't of the EU, it's of our education system. Whatever it's faults, the only place to be able to reform it from, is inside. UK gov is happy to write-off Cornwall, Wales, & the North as dead-losses, cancelling even basic rail electrification, in favour of HS2 that will only benefit London, & spread unaffordability in housing. The only engine for regional development, since UK bodies for that were dissolved, is the EU. London will flood before 2100 too

Comment: That's a whole debate to have in another place. Just please don't plug your personal political opinions in your answers.